# Using reactive webflux code inside of a @KafkaListener annotated method

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I am using spring-kafka to implement a consumer that reads messages from a certain topic. All of these messages are processed by them being exported into another system via a REST API. For that, the code uses the WebClient from the Spring Webflux project, which results in reactive code:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${some.topic}", groupId = "my-group-id")
  public void listenToTopic(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    
    // minimal, non-reactive code here (logging, serizializing the string)

    webClient.get().uri(...).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
       // long, reactive chain here
       .subscribe();
  }
```

Now I am wondering if this setup is reasonable or if this could cause a lot of issues because the KafkaListener logic from spring-kafka isn't inherently reactive. I wonder if it is necessary to use reactor-kafka instead.
My understanding of the whole reactive world and also the kafka world is very limited, but here is what I am currently assuming the above setup would entail:

1. The listenToTopic function will almost immediately return, because the bulk of the work is done in a reactive chain, which will not block the function from returning. This means that, from what I understand, the KafkaListener logic will assume that the message is properly processed right there and then, so it will probably acknowledge it and at some point also commit it. If I understand correctly, then that means that the processing of the messages could get out of order. Work could still be done in the previous, reactive chain while the KafkaListener already fetches the next record. This means if the application relies on the messages being fully processed in strict order, then the above setup would be bad. But if it does not, then the above setup would be okay?
2. Another issue with the above setup is that the application could overload itself with work if there are a lot of messages coming in. Because the listener function returns almost immediately, a large amount of messages could be processing inside of reactive chains at the same time.
3. The retry-logic that comes built in with the @KafkaListener logic would not really work here, because exceptions inside of the reactive chain would not trigger it. Any retry-logic would have to be handled by the reactive code inside of the listener function itself.
4. When using reactor-kafka instead of the @KafkaListener annotation, one could change the behaviour described in point 1. Because the listener would now be integrated into the reactive chain, it would be possible to acknowledge a message only when the reactive chain has actually finished. This way, from what I understand, the next message will only be fetched after one message is fully processed via the reactive chain. This would probably solve the issues/behaviour described in point 2-4 as well.

The question: Is my understanding of the situation correct? Are there other issues that could be caused by this setup that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; either switch to a non-reactive rest client (e.g. `RestTemplate`) or use `reactor-kafka` for the consumer.